# How to catch space bar event from input type number using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to catch space bar input from input type like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function  lala(aa){
    console.log(aa + " dasda");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "number" value =  "0.00" class = "no-spin" onchange='lala(this)' />
</body>
</html>
```

onchange does not trigger the space bar input. I would like to change the value to 0 again when space bar is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event is only fired when the input looses focus, not on each keystroke.

The `input` event does, for any *valid* input (and space isn't one in this case).

You can use `keyup` and then do your thing:

```
<input type="number" value="0.00" class="no-spin" onkeyup="lala(event, this)" />
```

You can check `aa.keyCode == 32` (aa being your "lala" argument name) to know if the key pressed was the spacebar, and then do your thing.

Something like this if you want this to happen when the value is empty:

```
function lala(event, input) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32 && !input.value) {
        input.value = '0.00';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this ?

1. I change type to `text` from `number` to allow space
2. I remove onchange event and created `addEventListener` to watch `keyup`
3. Instead value you should keep `0.00` in placeholder to make better user friendly.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
        document.querySelector("#test").value = '';
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="0.00" value="" class="no-spin" id="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` event to catch every change to the input field (you'll need to give the input field an id):

```
document.getElementById('input-id').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  // everything will be available here
});
```

you shouldn't declare javascript events as html attributes. it's [bad practice](https://rodolphe.breard.tf/post/javascript-why-you-shouldnt-use-html-event-attributes-anymore/)

Comment: +1 for the html attribute, event if it is easier to share code like this.

But the input event won't be fired for the spacebar on an input number.

Comment: thanks @kLabz I've updated the answer